# On Mac OS X (10.6.4) is there a keyboard shortcut to close all other windows

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager

On Mac OS X (10.6.4) is there a keyboard shortcut to close all other windows except the one with focus?

Answer (score 4):

### Not that I know of.

You can however hide all other applications with `Option`+`Command`+`H`.

Comment: Does ⌥⌘H work differently on 10.6? On earlier releases it only hides other applications (if the current application has multiple windows open, they will all remain visible).

Comment: @Chris: You are correct, all other applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an applescript to close all but the frontmost window of the current application. In snow leopard, you can put it in an automator service and give it a keyboard shortcut. Alternatively, you can use [Fastscripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to give it a shortcut.

**Edit:** I've added hiding other applications to the applescript.
**Edit #2:** OK, after testing I found the `repeat while  window 2 exists` actually didn't stop looping, causing nasty autoclose behaviour when opening new windows. The new code should be more robust.

```
with timeout of 2 seconds
  try
    tell application "System Events"
        set app_name to name of the first process whose frontmost is true
        set visible of (every process) to false -- hide everything
    end tell

    tell application app_name
        activate -- show frontmost application
        repeat with aWindow in (get every window)
            if index of aWindow > 1 then close aWindow
        end repeat
    end tell
  on error error_message number error_number
    display alert ("Something went wrong:") ¬
        message error_message ¬
        & (" Error number ") & error_number & "."
  end try
end timeout
```